# Python PIL doubling images

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw over 2 images, and I am getting this weird error. For most of the time the image drawing goes well.

[image: This is]     -or-  [image]

These are the two symbols as they normally would be. However here is what is being outputted randomly Most of the time this code works without a hitch but sometimes it does this:

[image]

So here is my code. This first one chooses ONE overlay image(not two)

```
   if 'Instant' in s.duration:
    durpic = Image.open('Dur-I.png')
elif 'round' in s.duration:
    durpic = Image.open('Dur-R.png')
    dnum = write_roman(int(re.search(r'\d+', s.duration).group()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(durpic)
    w, h = draw.textsize(dnum)
    draw.text((0, 0), dnum, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
elif 'min' in s.duration:
    if 'Concentration' in s.duration:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-CM.png')
    else:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-M.png')
    dnum = write_roman(int(re.search(r'\d+', s.duration).group()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(durpic)
    w, h = draw.textsize(dnum)
    draw.text((0, 0), dnum, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
elif 'hour' in s.duration:
    if 'Concentration' in s.duration:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-CH.png')
    else:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-H.png')
    dnum = write_roman(int(re.search(r'\d+', s.duration).group()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(durpic)
    w, h = draw.textsize(dnum)
    draw.text((0, 0), dnum, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
elif 'day' in s.duration:
    if 'Concentration' in s.duration:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-CD.png')
    else:
        durpic = Image.open('Dur-D.png')
    dnum = write_roman(int(re.search(r'\d+', s.duration).group()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(durpic)
    w, h = draw.textsize(dnum)
    draw.text((0, 0), dnum, (0, 0, 0), font=font)
elif 'Until' in s.duration:
    durpic = Image.open('Dur-R.png')
```

Placing the image over the base image

```
image_copy = scho.image
image_copy.paste(durpic, scho.point3, durpic)
imgpath = 'output/' + s.name + '.png'
image_copy.save(imgpath)
```

So any advice on what is causing this error? I could paste more code if needed or more output examples.

Comment: Your code is horribly repetitive! Maybe call a function passing in the imagename as a parameter and then the function can open the image and write on the duration.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for that "amazing" insight, and while I agree that it is repetitive. 1 this is the first thing I ever wrote in python and 2 I haven't cleaned it up cause it's a first pass. Yes it's repetitive, but it was the quickest and dirtiest way to hammer out a solution.

Comment: What is "amazing" is that when you extract repetitive code and put it in a function, it suddenly works much more consistently and becomes easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Okay..... so, yes that is true, but that's not where the error was coming from, notice my example doesn't have any overlayed text? I will be refactoring the code soon, but for right now, finding the error is more important to me.

Comment: Also on the too do list, is actually correctly place the text, another glitch I need to sort out which makes trying to condense this code even more obnoxious.